# I cant load simple data in a file while i dont see an error in my code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Just a program that writes data (in our case 3 integers) in a file with the name GRADES.

int main(void)
{
    int a=5,b=6,c=7;  //var declaration.
    FILE *point;      //Creating a pointer to work with a file.

    point = fopen("GRADES","w"); //we point the location to the memory where we wanna input data (in this case GRADES.c).
    fprintf(point,"%d\n %d\n %d",a,b,c); //calling function fprintf to load the data in the GRADES file.

    fclose(point);// Closing the file (optional) c usually close it without telling.

    return 0;

}

// i use the free open source platform CODE:BLOCKS
```

Comment: You don't see any error codes... but don't check for errors... hmmmmm...

Comment: Did you answered to a question here? cause i dont see any answer, and yes i m knew to this souldnt i ask for something i dont get for 2 days now? plus i read a book that says this code i wrote is correct but when i open the file to see the data , theres nothing in there, like my code and the actual file doesnt communicate for some reason, if someone could help me on this i would be gratefull

Comment: One example: `fopen` will `return` a `NULL` pointer if it fails.  You can check for an error like this: `if(!point) ... ;`

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a=5,b=6,c=7;
    FILE *point;

    point = fopen("GRADES","w");
    fprintf(point,"%d\n %d\n %d",a,b,c);

    if(!point)
    {
            printf("nothing happens");
    }

 return 0;

}
I tried itlike this i hope i m not totally unrelated, it didnt change  a thing, no message  from the if statement

Comment: `fprintf` `return`s how many bytes it has written.  What is this number?

Comment: I thank you for your time sir, i am apparently in a very low lvl at this point we re talking and i need to catch up more,goodnight.

Comment: Good luck. Let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking for errors you should be able to tell exactly what your problem is.

**fopen**

`fopen` will `return` `NULL` if it fails:

```
point = fopen("GRADES","w");
if(!point)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file!\n");
    return -1;
}
```

**fprintf**

`fprintf` will `return` how many bytes written.  If it fails, a negative number is `return`ed:

```
int num = fprintf(point,"%d\n %d\n %d",a,b,c);
if(num < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Write error!\n");
    return -1;
}
```

**fclose**

`fclose` will `return` `EOF` on error:

```
int status = fclose(point);
if(status == EOF)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to close file!\n");
    return -1;
}
```